# How can I place two toolbar items center and right, respectively?

Tags: macos, swiftui, toolbar

SwiftUI, MacOS

I'm trying to place toolbar Item A in the center and toolbar Item B on the right side of the toolbar.

Consider the following code.
If I comment out Item B, item A is placed correctly, and vice versa.
But if both are enabled, the placement goes wrong.

```
.toolbar () {
   ToolbarItem (placement: .principal) {
      Text("Item A")
   }
   
   ToolbarItem (placement: .status) {
      Text("Item B")
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: "But if both are enabled, the placement goes wrong"  How?  When you place two or more controls side by side, you are supposed to use `VStack` or `HStack`?

Comment: if you want them on the same toolbar center and right, try this: `ToolbarItem (placement: .navigationBarTrailing) { Text("Item B") }`

Comment: I guess the placement parameter is intended to place the items at the position you specify. I've not had succes with HStacks in the toolbar. .navigationBarTrailing is not available for MacOS.

Comment: @Thomas have you ever find a solution other than falling back to AppKit and NSToolbar?